# Importing a web pdf into R

Tags: r

I am trying to import a pdf that is on the web into R:

```
library(tm)

webpdf <- "https://www.lme.com/~/media/Files/Market%20data/COTR/2015/2015_01/Cotr%2019%20Jan%202015.pdf"
uri <- sprintf("file://%s", system.file(file.path("doc", webpdf), package = "tm"))
if(all(file.exists(Sys.which(c("pdfinfo", "pdftotext"))))) {
pdf <- readPDF(control = list(text = "-layout"))(elem = list(uri = uri),
                                                 language = "en",
                                                 id = "id1")
content(pdf)[1:13]
}
VCorpus(URISource(uri, mode = ""),
    readerControl = list(reader = readPDF(engine = "ghostscript")))
```

I have not been able to do this and get an error message:

```
Error in system2(gs_cmd, c("-dNODISPLAY -q", sprintf("-sFile=%s", shQuote(file)),  : 
  '""' not found
```

Answer (score 1):

Lots of problems with the initial setup. This will get you the PDF content, but you should ask another question for the `tm` `Corpus` issues you're going to have.

```
library(tm)
library(httr) # this will make it easier to get to https conent

webpdf <- "https://www.lme.com/~/media/Files/Market%20data/COTR/2015/2015_01/Cotr%2019%20Jan%202015.pdf"

doc <- "cotr.pdf"

# save the file locally, write_disk() will act like a cache
stop_for_status(GET(webpdf, write_disk(doc)))

if(all(file.exists(Sys.which(c("pdfinfo", "pdftotext"))))) {

  pdf <- readPDF(control = list(text = "-layout"))(elem = list(uri = doc),
                                                   language = "en",
                                                   id = "id1")
  # httr also has a "content()" so make the call explicit
  NLP::content(pdf)[1:13]

}

print(str(pdf))

## List of 2
##  $ content: chr [1:113] "Commitment of Trader Report - Market Report as of 2015/01/21" "" "Metal" "AA" ...
##  $ meta   :List of 7
##   ..$ author       : NULL
##   ..$ datetimestamp: POSIXlt[1:1], format: "2015-01-21 08:59:10"
##   ..$ description  : NULL
##   ..$ heading      : NULL
##   ..$ id           : chr "cotr.pdf"
##   ..$ language     : chr "en"
##   ..$ origin       : NULL
##   ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "TextDocumentMeta"
##  - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "PlainTextDocument" "TextDocument"
## NULL
```